# Jest encountered an unexpected token when trying to do snapshot testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm trying to run snapshot testing but running in to this error:
[photo of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elNWV.png)

I believe this is because I don't have a certain package installed but i'm not sure which one

.babelrc

```
{
"presets": ["react", "es2015"]
 }
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "ovals",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@types/reactstrap": "^6.4.4",
"babel": "^6.23.0",
"babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
"browser-cookies": "^1.2.0",
"chromedriver": "^2.46.0",
"firebase": "^5.8.2",
"firebase-tools": "^6.7.0",
"jest": "^23.6.0",
"jimp": "^0.5.6",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"react": "^16.8.1",
"react-async-script-loader": "^0.3.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
"react-dom": "^16.8.1",
"react-draggable": "^3.1.1",
"react-dropzone": "^8.0.4",
"react-icons": "^3.3.0",
"react-image-crop": "^6.0.12",
"react-paypal-button": "^2.0.3",
"react-popper": "^1.3.3",
"react-rnd": "^9.1.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "^2.1.8",
"react-spinners": "^0.5.1",
"react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
"react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
"reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
"save": "^2.3.3",
"selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "jest",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"deploy": "firebase deploy"
 },
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": [
">0.2%",
"not dead",
"not ie <= 11",
"not op_mini all"
 ],
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"enzyme": "^3.9.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.12.1"
 }
}
```

FileUploader.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {FaUpload} from 'react-icons/fa';
    import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
    import ImagePreview from './ImagePreview.js';
    const baseStyle = {
      width: "100%",
      height: 400,
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: '#808080',
      borderStyle: 'dashed',
      backgroundColor: "#dcdcdc",
      borderRadius: 5
    };
    const activeStyle = {
      borderStyle: 'solid',
      borderColor: '#6c6',
      backgroundColor: '#eee'
    };
    const rejectStyle = {
      borderStyle: 'solid',
      borderColor: '#c66',
      backgroundColor: '#eee'
    };
    class FileUploader extends Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.removeImage = this.removeImage.bind(this);
        let files = [];
        if(props.fileList !== null && props.fileList !== undefined){
          files = props.fileList;
        }
        this.state = {uploadedImages: files};
      }
      onDrop = (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) =>{
        let arr = this.state.uploadedImages;
        acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
        arr.push(file);
          });
        this.setState({uploadedImages: arr},function(){
          this.props.onUpload(this.state.uploadedImages);
        });
      }
      getPreviews(){
        if(this.state.uploadedImages === null || this.state.uploadedImages === 
    undefined){
          return (
            <div>
              <ImagePreview width="100px" height="100px"/>
              {/*<div style={emptyBox}/>*/}
            </div>);
        }else{
          const previews = this.state.uploadedImages.map(function(img, index) {
            return <ImagePreview img={URL.createObjectURL(img)} key={index} 
    width="100px" height="100px" onClick={() =>this.removeImage(index)}/>;
          }.bind(this));


      return (
        <div>
        {previews}
        <ImagePreview width="100px" height="100px"/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  removeImage(index){
    let arr = this.state.uploadedImages;
    arr.splice(index,1);
    this.setState({uploadedImages: arr});
  }
  render(){



    return(
      <div>
        <Dropzone accept="image/*" onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}>
        {({ getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive, isDragAccept, isDragReject, acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles }) => {
          let styles = {...baseStyle}
          styles = isDragActive ? {...styles, ...activeStyle} : styles
          styles = isDragReject ? {...styles, ...rejectStyle} : styles
            return (
              <div {...getRootProps()} style={styles}>
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                <div style={{margin: "auto", textAlign: "center", position: "relative", top: "30%"}}>
                  <FaUpload size="100"/><br/>
                  {!isDragReject &&<strong>Drag and drop or click here</strong>}
                  {isDragReject && <strong>You can only upload Images</strong>}
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          }}
        </Dropzone>
        <div style={{marginTop: "10px", border: "1px solid gray", padding: "5px"}}>
          {this.getPreviews()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
      }
    }
    export default FileUploader;
```

If anyone knows why i'm getting this error in the Fileupload and how to fix it that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you show the code from FileUploader.js?

Comment: @JoseA.Ayllón I've posted the FileUploder.js